Launch a Binder Native (C++) Service from Flutter Plugin Android
I have a C++ Binder service which I can run in adb shell by calling serviceName
In addition, when it is running I am able to get the service using platform-specific Java to interact with it:
Class localClass = Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager");
Method getService = localClass.getMethod("getService", new Class[] {String.class});
binder = (IBinder) getService.invoke(localClass, new Object[]{SERVICE_NAME});

I would like it so that the Binder service automatically starts when the app is launched. How can I start the C++ service with flutter code?
I could just execute it as a shell command: execute shell command from android but I would like to know if there is a better way.
This method works
try {
  Process su = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
  DataOutputStream outputStream = new DataOutputStream(su.getOutputStream());

  outputStream.writeBytes("service_program");
  outputStream.flush();
  outputStream.close();
} catch(IOException e){
  Log.d("Error", e.toString());
}

SystemClock.sleep(100);

But it seems hacky to me
